# How to check a received message type on OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I have declared three different message types in OMNeT++:

- `Layer`
- `Ack`
- `Reject`

What I want to achieve is that every node in my network can send any type of message mentioned above. So that every message type has its own variables. But since the `handleMessage(cMessage*)` function accepts `cMessage*` type, I need to know the type of message to be able to cast it accordingly.

How would I go about it?

Here is my `Layer` message type:

```cpp
message Layer {
    int layer;
    simtime_t timeFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each your message type is represented by a class that inherits from `cMessage`. Therefore, `dynamic_cast` may be used to recognize the type of message, for example this way:

```
void YourClass::handleMessage(cMessage * msg) {
  Layer * layer = dynamic_cast<Layer*> (msg);
  if (layer != nullptr) {
     // received Layer

  } else {
     Ack* ack = dynamic_cast<Ack*> (msg);
     if (ack != nullptr) {
       // received Ack

     } else {
       Reject* rej= dynamic_cast<Reject*> (msg);
       if (rej != nullptr) {
        // received Reject

     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just to add, I've found that `cMessage` also has a `messageKind` variable. This variable is `0` for a `cMessage`. So we can also set `messageKind` appropriately to distinguish the message type.